# How to remove a block of. code from a json using jq?

Tags: json, linux, bash, key, jq

I have a json file `temp.json` like this -

```
{
  "data": {
    "stuff": [
    .....
    ]
  },
  "time": {
    "metrics": 83
  }
}
```

I want to remove this particular block of code from the above json file -

```
,
"time": {
  "metrics": 83
}
```

After removal I want to rewrite new json in the same file so that new content in the same file will be -

```
{
  "data": {
    "stuff": [
    .....
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this possible to do by any chance?

**Note:** number 83 can be any number in general.

Comment: Here's a very good treatise on [in-place editing](https://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/). I personally use the Perl implementation of `sponge` provided in that article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an excellent tutorial: [Baeldung: Guide to Linux jq Command for JSON Processing](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json).

Maybe you can try something like this: `jq 'del(.time)' temp.json > temp2.json`.

Note that jq works at the *semantic* level; it's not just "text substitution". So things like the "comma" separators between objects will be deleted from the JSON text when you use jq to delete the object.

Experiment, and see what works best for your particular scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the link but what about the comma I have before `time`?

Comment: See my update.  More importantly - TRY it.  You'll see :)  Most important: read the article, try some examples, and experiment with different choices.  Please post back what you find :)  'Hope that helps ... at least a little.